# Why does string.match( /(regexp)/ ) with parentheses return the match twice?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does `string.match( /(regexp)/ );` with parentheses return the match twice?

For instance: `"abcdef".match(/(cd)/);`returns two instances of `cd`: `["cd","cd"]`

I've looked in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).  It doesn't say anything about returning the match multiple times.

I even looked in the [ECMA docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

There's a workaround by just grabbing the `[1]` index `string.match()` but I couldn't find an explanation in the docs.

Comment: An alternative workaround would be to use the `/g` flag.

Answer (score 6):

Let's follow the docs on [RegExp.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the
>   same result as RegExp.exec(str).

Ok, go to [RegExp.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

> If the match succeeds, the exec method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has
>   the **matched text as the first item**, and then one item for each
>   capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was
>   captured.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, the MDN docs (here's a [Wayback snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20140227011200/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) of it right now) are indeed silent on this, but I bet `match` returns the entire match first, just like [RegExp.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

[image]

Here's a test:

```
"abcdef".match(/(bc).?(e)/)
=> ["bcde", "bc", "e"]
```